# How to install Cfengine in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I am Looking for a way to install cfenguine in my Ubuntu. Could somedoby help me with that ?

Thank you.

Comment: is that "cfenguine" or cfengine"?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command on terminal to install `cfengine3`,

```
sudo apt-get install cfengine3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have few other packages to install cfengine in your Ubuntu.

Open your terminal and paste these commands carefully one after one

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install tokyocabinet-bin
wget -qO- http://cfengine.com/pub/gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://cfengine.com/pub/apt/packages stable main" >  \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cfengine-community.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cfengine-community
```

credit goes here : http://cfengine.com/cfengine-linux-distros

Comment: yes it do. you want log ? I can provide.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/m5h6ebg8r/ @AvinashRaj

Comment: not separate one. @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 0):

This Tutorial would help you for your purpose :

[How to install Cfengine](http://blog.refu.co/?p=843)

Hope it helps .

From the tutorial (added by @waltinator):

An introductory tutorial to CFEngine and Ubuntu

An introductory tutorial to using CFEngine with Ubuntu Linux. CFEngine is a configuration management system utilized in large system administration. It uses promise theory according to which everything can be thought of as a promise to be kept by different resources in the system. Combining promises with patterns to describe where and when promises should apply is the essence of the engine’s operation. We will see how compile and install the engine in Ubuntu Linux and how to run a few simple examples.

Comment: Even that link may answer the question exactly , please place part of the answer here for reference